# Android remote database connection using JSON

Tags: android

We are working on android projects. We need to connect our android application
to MSSQL remote Server. For login page in android we were able to connect 
to MSSQL Server via php scripts. Now we are having another page...i.e 
calendar...we need to connect this to MSSQL. 
  We found one option in

http://blog.sptechnolab.com/2011/02/10/android/android-connecting-to-mysql-using-php/ 
In this link they used JSON and MYSQL. We got the concept from this link but it will be  helpful for us if anybody show the php scripts with MSSQL for both storing and retrieving data using JSON.

```
 We will be thankful to you.
```

Comment: This is really not an android question.  From what I understand, you want to write and parse JSON via PHP.  You should change your tag appropriately.

Comment: no no we want to connect our android calendar page to remote MSSQL Server and hence we posted the tag as android.

Comment: We want to write and parse JSON via PHP(MSSQL). Please send us some sample code. It will be helpful for us.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Android Ksoap2 library](http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/) to call web services from android.
On the server side implement [Soap based PHP web service](http://php.net/manual/en/book.soap.php).

I guess this is more easier way than your tutorial.

Comment: But if you really needs JSON, use the default [Android package](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/package-summary.html) . This is an example for parsing [JSON in android](http://www.androidcompetencycenter.com/2009/10/json-parsing-in-android/)